# DFS recursively searching the values in a list of dictionaries for each key

Tags: python, depth-first-search

Given the list of dictionaries:

```
[{"a": ["b", "c", "d"]},
 {"b": ["e", "z", "g"]},
 {"g": ["c", "f", "z"]},  
 {"z": ["w", "y", "x"]}]
```

it is implied `"a"` **directly** depends upon `"b", "c", and "d"`
it is implied `"a"` **indirectly** depends upon `"e", "z", "g", "f", "w", "y", "z"` because its direct dependencies have these dependencies (both direct and indirect).

Therefore I am looking for a depth search that can give a list of dictionaries of each key with its respective indirect dependencies (*excluding the direct ones*) such that the resulting output for the data above would look like:

```
[{"a": ["e", "z", "g", "f", "w", "y", "z"]},
 {"b": ["c", "f", "w", "y", "x"]},
 {"g": ["w", "y", "x"]},  
 {"z": []}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here a possible solution for your problem:

```py
def dfs(dictionary : dict, start : str, visited : set) -> set:
    # Add the current key to the visited set
    visited.add(start)

    # If the current key has no dependencies return the visited set
    if dictionary.get(start) is None:
        return visited

    # For each dependency of the current key, if it is not visited, call dfs on it
    # This will find all the dependencies of that dependency and so on, until there are no more dependencies.
    for value in dictionary.get(start):
        if value not in visited:
            dfs(dictionary, value, visited)

    # Return the visited set
    return visited

def indirect_dependenices(list_of_dictionaries : list) -> list:
    # Merge all the dictionaries into one
    merged_dictionary = {key:value for dictionary in list_of_dictionaries for key,value in dictionary.items()}

    # Initialize the output list
    output = []

    for key in merged_dictionary:
        visited = set()
        # for each key in the dictionary find among the other all its dependencies (both direct and indirect)
        dependencies = dfs(merged_dictionary, key, visited)

        # remove the direct dependencies
        dependencies = dependencies - set(merged_dictionary.get(key)) - set([key])
        
        # add the key and its indirect dependencies to the output
        output.append({key: list(dependencies)})
            
    return output

def main():
    # Initialize the list of dictionaries
    list_of_dictionaries = [{"a": ["b", "c", "d"]}, {"b":["e", "z", "g"]}, {"g":["c", "f", "z"]}, {"z":["w", "y", "x"]}]

    output = indirect_dependenices(list_of_dictionaries)
    print(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code provided first merges the list of dictionaries into a single dictionary and then cycles through all the keys and performs a DFS to look for all the dependencies (both direct and indirect) of that key. Before appending the result to the output the direct dependencies are removed from the list.

Comment: just a small correction `dependencies = dependencies - set(merged_dictionary.get(key)) - set([key])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function that checks each list value is a key of a list.

You need to use a function that loops through the list of values for each key. If the found key is a node in the list, all indirect dependencies are collected. The function returns a list of values formatted by the "collect_dependencies" function.

The recursive function "collect_dependencies" checks each value of the list if it is an indirect key of the list.

```
def collect_dependencies(graph, node, dependencies):
    """
    Recursive function to collect indirect dependencies for a given node in a graph
    """
    if node not in graph: # If node is not in graph, return False
        return False
    for neighbor in graph[node]: # Looping through each neighbor of the node
        if neighbor in graph: # Checking if the neighbor is a node in the graph
            collect_dependencies(graph, neighbor, dependencies) # Collecting indirect dependencies for the neighbor
        elif neighbor not in dependencies: # Checking if the neighbor is not already in the list of dependencies
            dependencies.append(neighbor) # Adding the neighbor to the list of dependencies

            
def get_indirect_dependencies(graph):
    
    indirect_dependencies = [] # List to store indirect dependencies
    for key in graph.keys(): # Looping through each node in the graph
        dependencies = [] # List to store dependencies for each node
        for neighbor in graph[key]: # Looping through each neighbor of the node
            if neighbor in graph: # Checking if the neighbor is a node in the graph
                collect_dependencies(graph, neighbor, dependencies) # Collecting indirect dependencies for the neighbor
        if not dependencies: # Checking if there are any dependencies
            continue # If there are no dependencies, skip to the next node
        indirect_dependencies.append({key: dependencies}) # Adding the node and its dependencies to the list of indirect dependencies
    return indirect_dependencies

graph = {
    "a": ["b", "c", "d"],
    "b": ["e", "z", "g"],
    "g": ["c", "f", "z"],
    "z": ["w", "y", "x"],
}

indirect_dependencies = get_indirect_dependencies(graph)

for dependency in indirect_dependencies:
    print(dependency)
```